# BigQuery NodeJs Library - Error while accessing external source in Google Drive

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, node-modules

I'm trying to run a query in `BigQuery` using the `NodeJS SDK` but I'm getting an error saying

> "Errors: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found".

The table is an external table with a source format like `GOOGLE_SHEETS`.

I configured the big query with the following code, adding additional scope. My default credential has access to drive. Note: The bq command is working.

```js
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

const bigquery = new BigQuery({
    projectId: "my-dataset",
    scopes: [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
    ],
});
```

What do I miss? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#enable-google-drive) “Accessing data hosted within Google Drive requires an additional OAuth scope, both when defining the federated source as well as during query execution”.

When using the BigQuery API it’s stated that it’s needed to request the OAuth scope for Google Drive in addition to the scope for BigQuery. In the aforementioned link you will also find examples explicitly creating credentials with the required scopes in other languages.

To make things easier I would suggest you to use [Google Auth Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs), including as scopes:

```
scopes: [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"
    ]
```